# Recasting of double passives

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, passive-voice

According to Garner's fourth edition,

> Recasting of the first passive verb form into the active voice
> clarifies the sense:
>
> *The prisoners were ordered to be
> shot* → Active/Passive: *He ordered them (to be) shot*
>
> Yet, in the following example, a recasting of the first passive verb into
> the active voice **does not make sense**:
>
> *The contention has been attempted to be made.* → *He attempted it to be made.*
>
> The last-quoted sentence is
> **un-English**

What does the author exactly mean by the vague expressions "not make sense" or "be un-English"?

Secondly, would *He attempted the contention made* be a better option?

Comment: ***The contention has been attempted to be made.*** This makes no grammatical sense to me. No wonder it can't be recast to indicative. If I had to rewrite it I would say, "An attempt has been made to make the contention."

Comment: To convert a passive to an active, there must be an agent in the passive: The contention has been attempted to be made. → The contention has been attempted, **by him**, to be made. → He has attempted to make the contention.

Comment: Although 'No error analysis has been attempted' sounds fine, 'a delivery has been attempted to be made' is at best unidiomatic. I'd say Fowler needs a new update.

Comment: (1) *The contention has been attempted.* (2) *He attempted to contend.* The addition of *be made* is deliberately confusing, and I'm not sure what point is being made by using it.

Comment: @JasonBassford _The contention has been **(attempted to be)** made_ or  _The contention has been attempted **(to be made)**_?

Comment: @GJC No, you miss my point. None of the *to be made* versions (in the passive or active voice) is idiomatic. I can see no reason to come up with some exercise that involves something so unidiomatic as to be essentially (even if not technically) ungrammatical. But since the author correctly says *un-English*, there might be some reason for it that isn't obvious from the quoted context. Although, from what I can infer without certainty, it seems the author might not think the passive-voice version is *un-English*. (Something I entirely disagree with.)

Comment: @JasonBassford _"Recently I heard it suggested by a friend that..." Grammatically speaking, that sentence contains the implied _being_ after _it_, so it’s in the passive voice_. Why is_being_ chosen, instead of just _be_? The suggestion was heard in its entirety