# Recommended: passive + to-infinitive

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives

*Fowler’s Dictionary* supports examples like the following in the passive, but not their active counterparts

> *The committee is being **recommend**ed to approve the proposals*

However, it says about double passives as follows

> Such constructions (*no greater thrill can be hoped to be enjoyed*) are awkward because they have no active
> counterpart, **We hope no greater thrill to be enjoyed*.

What's the reason for this discrepancy?

Comment: The example is legalese, and not idiomatic for normal use.

Comment: Can you provide more complete examples please?I am tempted to vote for closure because of lack of clarity but realise I may simply not understand.

Comment: **Passive** *The committee is being recommended [by the King] to approve the proposals.* --**Active** *The King is recommending [that] the committee approve the proposals* -- **Passive** they attempted the pretext to be sold. = they attempted the pretext **that was** to be sold [by them]. =  --**Active** they attempted the pretext **that they intended to sell**.

Comment: @Greybeard that's paraphrasing

Comment: What does "The committee is being recommended to approve the proposals" mean? Does "recommend" mean "advised", "told"? In this case it would be a real passive, "The chairman recommended [cf. told, advised] the committee to approve the proposal" => "The committee was recommended to approve the proposals (by the chairman). To me that sounds odd. Or does it mean something very different, like "praised", "lauded" perhaps? In this case it would not really be a passive, but a stative adjective, like "excited" or "bored." But if so, I'm not familiar with that use of "recommended." So, please clarify.

Comment: The examples seem to me real clunkers, even though we know what they are supposed to mean.  But before your question can be answered properly you need to look at the use of the basic form of the verb.  Then you will find it easier to explain clearly what might or might not be odd about the usage you mention.

Comment: @Tuffy: *even though we know what they are supposed to mean?* So far as I'm aware, *The committee is being recommended to approve the proposals* could mean EITHER that the king is directly urging the *committee* to approve something, OR that he's proposing to *some unspecified body* that they should choose the committee to do the approving, rather than having that approval carried out by some other (also unspecified) body.

Comment: I don't get that "no active counterpart" business. Passive *no greater thrill can be hoped to be enjoyed* = Active *we can hope to enjoy no greater thrill*

Comment: @FumbleFingers https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/539036/recasting-of-double-passives

Comment: *The contention has been attempted to be made* = *He attempted to make the contention*. I think it's the same issue here as that earlier one. These "double passives" are almost always gonna be seriously "ugly" anyway, but it's not that they can't be converted to "active" voice ***at all*** - it's just that you can't make just the *first* element active while retaining the passive form for the *second* element.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Linguistically, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice#Double_passives

Comment: I'm basically with Fowler, who calls this construction "clumsy and incorrect". I don't really care if strictly speaking double passives are actually "parseable". It's an ugly format, hardly worth bothering with in *any* context, and certainly not worth trying to faithfully transform from passive to active.